# Передать value из тега в php

Tags: php

```html
<select>
        <option value = 10>10</option>
        <option value = 11>11</option>
        <option value = 12>12</option>
</select>
```

Как передать значение value в переменную php,для дальнейшей работы с ней?

Comment: Какие умные браузеры пошли, уже и пробелы в атрибутах лишние им нипочём)

Comment: В переменную php передать значение value невозможно. Когда вы манипулируете этим select никаких переменных php не существует. Вы можете выполнить http запрос в php скрипт, в котором(в запросе) и передать нужные данные на обработку.

Comment: @vp_arth Я просто никогда не занимался написанием сайтов, а тут пришлось сделать один. Можно пример кода,пожалуйста? Там суть в том,чтобы значение,которое выбрал пользователь из списка умножалось на 20 и выводился результат

Comment: @Oleg Tsvetkov  один из вариантов, это доставать значения value из базы данных, чтобы получать значения. Что у вас хранится в данном выборе и уберите пробелы между <option value=11> и так далее.

Comment: @Eric7777777  Как раз таки эти значения должны попадать в базу данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заверните поле ввода в `<form>` и добавьте ему name(`name=number`):

```
<form action="/mul20.php">
  <select name="number">
     <option value=10>10</option>
     <option value=11>11</option>
     <option value=12>12</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

В action формы укажите ссылку на ваш php скрипт.

### mul20.php

```
<?php
// Получаем данные формы
$num = (int)$_REQUEST['number'] ?? 0;
echo $num * 20; // Умножаем на 20 и выводим
```